# MySQL Community Server Limitations

Tags: mysql, database

Could anyone please tell what are the limitations to MySQL Community Server & the pros of a MySQL Enterprise Server?

The following would be our daily transactional activity with the DB

> Atleast 10 million records would be created and updated on a person day basis.
>
> Scheduled Procedures would be acting on the records in addition to the application accessing them.

I am concerned about the DB capacity (DB size threshold,etc) and if it would withstand huge volume of data when i opt for MySQL Community Server.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Difference between MySQL CE and MySQL Enterprise edition?**

Difference between the community edition and the enterprise edition is added support and tools. The server itself is the same, but the enterprise edition gets updated more frequently and it is stable with quick bug fix support.
It would be safe and will not make any problem if the decide to move on to ORACLE in future.

**MySQL Enterprise subscriptions include:**

1. MySQL Enterprise Server which is the most reliable, secure and
   up-to-date version of the world’s most popular open source database
2. The MySQL Enterprise Monitor provides monitoring and automated Ad visors to help you eliminate security vulnerabilities, improve replication, optimize performance, and more
3. MySQL Technical Support enables you to get your toughest technical questions answered quickly.
4. MySQL Consultative Support, available with MySQL Enterprise Platinum gives you tailored advise from the MySQL Support team on how to properly design and tune your MySQL servers, schema, queries, and replication set-up for better performance.

**MySQL Community Server:**

1. Freely available under the open source GPL license
2. In a MyISAM table with dynamic (variable length) rows, the index
   file for the table (tablename.MYI) stores row locations using 32-bit
   pointers into the data file (tablename.MYD). That means it can
   address only 4GB of space.

Comment: Another advantage of MySQL Enterprise edition over Community edition is it provides the MySQL Thread Pool.
The Thread Pool provides a highly scalable, queue-based thread-handling model designed to reduce
overhead in managing client connections and statement execution threads.

Comment: with this said? can i just subscribe to one license and use it in 5 server?